# Unwanted bonding lines (dynamically created) in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, graph, append

I have a problem: when I dynamically create several lines using the same drawing functions, lines have bondings, as though all points of them belong to only one line. I tried: setting different classes, different id, I put them into different groups, also I tried using different instances of functions, tried using .append, .enter.append. But effect is the same. 
I would be very grateful for your help in solving this problem.

The line highlighted in red is unwanted bonding: [click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQxcN.png).

[Here jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfedorov1/bmb0wLro/12/). I tried to reduce the code as much as possible. Procedure to reproduce the effect: click 'Add', click 'Play', if graph changed, click pause, and click 'Add'.

```
/* added lines */
/***************/
    line_added = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("monotone")
        .defined(function(d) { 
            if($.inArray(d.z, all_z_added)!=-1) 
            {
                if(!d.predicted)
                    return y(d.y); 
            };
        })
        .x(function(d) {return x(d.x);})
        .y(function(d) {return y(d.y);});


    p_line_added = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("monotone")
        .defined(function(d, i) { 
            if($.inArray(data[i].z, all_z_added)!=-1)
            {
                if(data[i].predicted)
                {
                    return y(data[i].y); 
                }
                else
                {
                    if(data[i+1]!=undefined && data[i-1]!=undefined)
                    {
                        if(!data[i].predicted && data[i+1].predicted)
                            return y(data[i].y); 
                    }
                };
            };
        })
        .x(function(d) {return x(d.x);})
        .y(function(d) {return y(d.y);});


function recreate_added()
{
    svg.selectAll(".line_added").remove(); 
    svg.selectAll(".p_line_added").remove();  

    // var all = svg.selectAll("line").data([data], function(d) { return d});

    for(var k in all_z_added)
    {


        svg.append("path")
        .data([data])     
        .attr("class", "line_added line_added" + all_z_added[k] )
        .attr("id", "al" + all_z_added[k] )
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .attr("d", line_added);   

        svg.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "p_line_added p_line_added" + all_z_added[k] )
        .attr("id", "apl" + all_z_added[k] )
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .attr("d", p_line_added); 

    //     all.enter().append("path")
    //     .attr("class", "line_added line_added" + all_z_added[k] )
    //     .attr("id", "al" + all_z_added[k] )
    //     .attr("d", line_added);   

    //     all.enter().append("path")
    //     .attr("class", "p_line_added p_line_added" + all_z_added[k] )
    //     .attr("id", "apl" + all_z_added[k] )
    //     .attr("d", p_line_added); 

        // svg.append("g")
        // .attr("class", "line_added g" + all_z_added[k] )
        // .attr("id", "g" + all_z_added[k] )

        //     .append("path")
        //     .data([data])     
        //     .attr("class", "line_added line_added" + all_z_added[k] )
        //     .attr("id", "al" + all_z_added[k] )
        //     .style('fill', 'none')
        //     .attr("d", line_added);   


        // svg.append("g")
        // .attr("class", "line_added pg" + all_z_added[k] )
        // .attr("id", "pg" + all_z_added[k] )

        //     .append("path")
        //     .data([data])
        //     .attr("class", "p_line_added p_line_added" + all_z_added[k] )
        //     .attr("id", "apl" + all_z_added[k] )
        //     .style('fill', 'none')
        //     .attr("d", p_line_added); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you please create a jsfiddle (inputing your Html, Css and d3/jquery data) in order to checkout what is happening?

I guess you should not be using `interpolate` function with 'basis', draing B-Splines with these 'bondings'. Take a look: at the [d3 documentation here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_interpolate). Also, try to remove the `interpolate` function. x and y functions should be enough.

Comment: I tried to reduce the code as much as possible. [Here jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfedorov1/bmb0wLro/12/). Procedure to reproduce the effect: click 'Add', click 'Play', if graph changed, click pause, and click 'Add'. Adding and removing of 'interpolate' didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I tried just commenting on interpolate, and seems like bonding disappeared. Take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmb0wLro/14/). Maybe I might not figured out what kind of bonding effect you are trying to remove, but if I pause and hit Add again, I see a line with no curves at all (including the one connecting the dots).

Comment: I added new link to description of my question. It should explain what kind of bonding effect I trying to remove. When I commenting interpolate, effect is the same. I think that problem with array. I used different data for different line from one array. Maybe if I will use different arrays problem will solved.

Comment: It was good point. This is my solution:         [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfedorov1/bmb0wLro/19/) (lines 601-614)